# Using DNNLinearCombinedEstimator in tensorflow for multilabel classification

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, built-in, multilabel-classification

I have a multilabel dataset that I would like to use a wide-n-deep neural network to classify the samples.

This is a very small example just to test:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

training_df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'feature1': np.random.rand(10),
        'feature2': np.random.rand(10),
        'feature3': np.random.rand(10),
        'feature4': np.random.randint(0, 3, 10),
        'feature5': np.random.randint(0, 3, 10),
        'feature6': np.random.randint(0, 3, 10),
        'target1': np.random.randint(0, 2, 10),
        'target2': np.random.randint(0, 2, 10),
        'target3': np.random.randint(0, 2, 10)
    }
)
features = ['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3','feature4', 'feature5', 'feature6']
targets = ['target1', 'target2', 'target3']
Categorical_Cols = ['feature4', 'feature5', 'feature6']
Numerical_Cols = ['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3']


wide_columns = [tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(key=x, vocabulary_list=[0, 1, -1])
                                    for x in Categorical_Cols]


deep_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(x) for x in Numerical_Cols]


def wrap_dataset(df, features, labels):
  dataset = (
      tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
          (
              tf.cast(df[features].values, tf.float32),
              tf.cast(df[labels].values, tf.int32),
          )
      )
  )

  return(dataset)

input_fn_train = wrap_dataset(training_df, features, targets)

m = tf.contrib.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedEstimator(
          head=tf.contrib.estimator.multi_label_head(n_classes=2),
          # wide settings
          linear_feature_columns=wide_columns,
          #     linear_optimizer=tf.train.FtrlOptimizer(...),
          # deep settings
          dnn_feature_columns=deep_columns,
          #     dnn_optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(...),
          dnn_hidden_units=[10, 30, 10])

m.train(input_fn=input_fn_train)
```

In this example, we have 6 features including:

- 3 numerical features: feature1, feature2, and feature3
- 3 categorical features: feature4, feature5, and feature6

where each sample has three labels and each label has a binary value: 0 or 1.

The error is about the input function and I cannot figure out how to define the input function in a correct way.
Any help to correct the code is appreciated.

UPDATE: The error is:

```
TypeError: <TensorSliceDataset shapes: ((6,), (3,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)> is not a callable object
```

Comment: Can you post what is your error?

Comment: I just added the error to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out how to make the code working. I post it here to help people who would like to do multi-label classification using built-in function `DNNLinearCombinedEstimator` from tensorflow package, version 1.13.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
# from tensorflow import contrib
tf.enable_eager_execution()

training_df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'feature1': np.random.rand(10),
        'feature2': np.random.rand(10),
        'feature3': np.random.rand(10),
        'feature4': np.random.randint(0, 3, 10),
        'feature5': np.random.randint(0, 3, 10),
        'feature6': np.random.randint(0, 3, 10),
        'target1': np.random.randint(0, 2, 10),
        'target2': np.random.randint(0, 2, 10),
        'target3': np.random.randint(0, 2, 10)
    }
)
features = ['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3','feature4', 'feature5', 'feature6']
targets = ['target1', 'target2', 'target3']
Categorical_Cols = ['feature4', 'feature5', 'feature6']
Numerical_Cols = ['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3']


wide_columns = [tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(key=x, vocabulary_list=[0, 1, -1])
                                    for x in Categorical_Cols]


deep_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(x) for x in Numerical_Cols]


def input_fn(df):
  # Creates a dictionary mapping from each continuous feature column name (k) to
  # the values of that column stored in a constant Tensor.
  continuous_cols = {k: tf.constant(df[k].values)
                     for k in Numerical_Cols}
  # Creates a dictionary mapping from each categorical feature column name (k)
  # to the values of that column stored in a tf.SparseTensor.
  categorical_cols = {k: tf.SparseTensor(
      indices=[[i, 0] for i in range(df[k].size)],
      values=df[k].values,
      dense_shape=[df[k].size, 1])
                      for k in Categorical_Cols}
  # Merges the two dictionaries into one.
  feature_cols = continuous_cols.copy()
  feature_cols.update(categorical_cols)

  labels =tf.convert_to_tensor(training_df.as_matrix(training_df[targets].columns.tolist()), dtype=tf.int32)

  return feature_cols, labels



def train_input_fn():
  return input_fn(training_df)

def eval_input_fn():
  return input_fn(training_df)



m = tf.contrib.learn.DNNLinearCombinedEstimator(
          head=tf.contrib.learn.multi_label_head(n_classes=3),
          # wide settings
          linear_feature_columns=wide_columns,
          #     linear_optimizer=tf.train.FtrlOptimizer(...),
          # deep settings
          dnn_feature_columns=deep_columns,
          #     dnn_optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(...),
          dnn_hidden_units=[10, 10])

m.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=20)
results = m.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn, steps=1)
print("#########################################################")
for key in sorted(results):
    print("%s: %s" % (key, results[key]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it says it is not a callable object, you can simply add lambda and it should work

`input_fn_train = lambda: wrap_dataset(training_df, features, targets)`

Also I think you need to sort out how you pass your data to the Estimator. It might take dictionaries since you are using feature columns. Right now you are passing tensors and not dictionary of Tensors. Check out this [useful post](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/introducing-tensorflow-feature-columns.html).